# Calling super().__init__() gives the wrong method when it is overridden

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have a base class and a sub class. In the base class I have an instance method which is called in `__init__`. In the sub class I have overridden this method. The `super()` call in the sub class does not call the original base method but the overridden sub class method. Why?

```py
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, value):

        self.value = value
        self.transformed_value = self.create_value(value)

    def create_value(self, value):

        print("base")
        return value + 1

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, value):

        super().__init__(value)

    def create_value(self, value):
        print("sub")
        return value + 2

s = SubClass(3)
```

I expect the print output to be "base", but the actual output is "sub". How can I modify the code to get "base" without explicitly calling `BaseClass.create_value(self, value)` in the `__init__` of `BaseClass`?

Comment: You can't. `self.create_value(value)` uses the type of `self`, which you simply do not know when defining `BaseClass.__init__`. If you really want `BaseClass.create_value` to be called, you need to do so explicitly. `s` is an instance of `SubClass`, so `self.create_value` will resolve to `SubClass.create_value` no matter where it happens to be called.

Comment: @chepner - this should be the answer. I would upvote it.

Comment: If you intend to call the base.method from `base.__init__` then why are you overriding that method in the subclass to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed. That means when you write

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.transformed_value = self.create_value(value)
```

is doesn't matter which class that method belongs to when evaluating `self.create_value`: it only matters what the *type* of `self` is when the method is called.

When you call `SubClass(3)`, you eventually call `SubClass.__init__`, which immediately calls `BaseClass.__init__` with an argument of type `SubClass`. Since `SubClass.create_value` is defined, that's what `self.create_value` resolves to.

If, for whatever reason, you insist the `BaseClass.__init__` calls `BaseClass.create_value` on its `self` argument, you have to do so explicitly with `BaseClass.create_value(self, value)`. However, that's rarely a good idea. If the type of `self` wants a method it overrides to be called, that's *its* responsibility to do so, by using `super` itself:

```
def create_value(self, value):
    rv = super().create_value()
    print("sub")
    return value + 2  # Or perhaps do something with rv first?
```

Comment: Originally I had wanted a SubClass instance that would be instantiated with base.create_value calls and also have subclass.create_value as its method - but your answer suggests that I should refactor my code. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes, that sounds like `BaseClass.__init__` and `BaseClass.create_value` should both use a common third method, rather than `__init__` using `create_value` directly (which is similar to [Swadhikar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043080/1126841)).

Comment: Could you explain further why BaseClass.create_value(self, value) is usually a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

Further to add to @chepner's elegant answer, if you want the parent class to call it's own method, you may modify the parent class as below:

```
class BaseClass:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.transformed_value = self.base_create_value(value)     # use the renamed reference

    def create_value(self, value):
        print("base")
        return value + 1

    base_create_value = create_value   # create a local reference to the method
```

In the above `BaseClass`, we are creating a simple reference to a parent method and are using the same inside its own `__init__` method. By doing so, we can continue to make use of this reference object even if the base class' method is overridden and when it is called by the child instance.